# Explain this C code to reverse a string

Tags: c, string, algorithm, reverse

I dont really understand what the last while loop is doing, can someone explain it?

```
void reverse(char *str) { 
    char * end = str; 
    char tmp; 

    if (str) {
        while (*end) { 
            ++end;
        }
        --end; 
        while (str < end) {
            tmp = *str; 
            *str++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone walk me through the example "hello"?

Comment: Have you tried drawing this out on paper?  Try writing out `h e l l o \0` on a piece of paper and walk through where `str` and `end` point and what `tmp` contains at each step through the code.  Is there a specific piece of the code that you find confusing?

Comment: its swapping characters from each end, moving towards the middle...

Comment: Nice to see a solution that doesn't invoke `strlen()`

Comment: How about stepping through the code in a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's basically happening in that innermost while loop is that in each iteration, the characters pointed to by `str` and `end` get swapped, `str` gets incremented to point to the next character, and `end` is decremented to point to the previous one.

Using "hello" as an example:

```
v   v
hello
 v v 
oellh
  v
olleh
```

And then the loop ends, as `str` = `end`.

Answer (score 11):

The basic idea behind this code is to work in two passes:

1. In the first pass, we end up with a pointer to the last character to the string.
2. In the second pass, we turn the string around, assisted by the knowledge of where the string ends.

This first pass is given by the following logic:

```
char *end = str;
while (*end) { 
    ++end;
}
--end;
```

This `while` loop begins with the `end` pointer pointing at the start of the string.  It then continuously advances the `end` pointer forward one step until the loop condition `*end` no longer evaluates to true.  Because C strings are null-terminated, the loop condition will evaluate to true as long as the `end` pointer points somewhere in the middle of the string rather than at the null terminator at the end of the string.  Thus, when this loop ends, the `end` pointer will have walked all the way to the end of the string and stopped at the null terminator.  We then execute `--end` to back up the pointer one step.  At this point, the `end` pointer points to the very last character in the string.  Here's an example with "Hello:"

```
 H e l l o
 ^       ^
 |       |
str     end
```

Now that we have this `end` pointer, we actually run the logic to reverse the string.  This is given by this code:

```
while (str < end) {
    tmp = *str; 
    *str++ = *end;
    *end-- = tmp;
}
```

The idea behind this code is that until the start and end pointers of the string have crossed over one another, we swap the values they point at, then march the two pointers inward toward one another.  If we rewrite this to the equivalent by slightly more verbose

```
while (str < end) {
    tmp = *str; 
    *str = *end;
    *end = tmp;

    ++str;
    --end;
}
```

Then it may be a bit easier to see how this works.  The first three lines of this modified loop exchange the values pointed at by the start and end pointers, and the next two lines move the pointers inward.  Here's an example:

```
 H e l l o
 ^       ^
 |       |
str     end

 o e l l H
   ^   ^
   |   |
  str end

 o l l e H
     ^
     |
  str end
```

At this point, the two pointers meet, and we have correctly reversed the string.

Note that there's an unusual edge case we have to take into account here, and that's what happens when the string is the empty string.  If this happens, then the first loop will behave a bit weirdly.  In particular, this code:

```
char *end = str;
while (*end) { 
    ++end;
}
--end;
```

Will never execute the body of the loop, because the `end` pointer will start off pointing to the null terminator.  The loop therefore does nothing, and we end up backing up `end` *one step before the string starts!*  This is an invalid pointer, and dereferencing it will have undefined results.  But fortunately, in this case, nothing happens, because the loop to reverse the string has this condition:

```
while (str < end)
```

This is immediately false if `end` is one step before the string starts, so nothing happens.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first while finds the last character; so, after it, `end` will point to it.

The second while swaps the character pointed by `str` with the one pointed by `end`, and moves `str` onward of 1 character and `end` backward of 1 character. This way, the characters are swapped going from the extern of the string to the inside.

The look ends when `end` starts to point to a character before `str`, which means that we reached the center of the string and all the characters have been already swapped.

"Hello" example:

```
S   E            S   E
V   V            V   V
Hello  >>swap>>  oellH

>>pointer increment/decrement>>

 S E              S E
 V V              V V
oellH  >>swap>>  olleH

>>pointer increment/decrement>>
it would result in

  E                
  S                
  V                
olleH

but now str is no longer before end, so the loop terminates
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what it does is this.

```
void reverse(char *str) { 
    char * end = str;  // copy the pointer 
    char tmp; 

    if (str) {
        // Now step through the string until you get to the last character.
        // which will be the null terminator \0
        while (*end) { 
            ++end;
        }
        // One step back, and we're pointing at the last actual character.
        --end; 
        // Now.  Move the start at either end and work your way inwards until
        // they meet in the middle.
        while (str < end) {
            // take copy of left character into tmp
            tmp = *str; 
            // copy right character into left position and move left pointer right
            *str++ = *end;
            // copy tmp character into right position and move right pointer left
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
  int i=0,lenght,j;
  char str[100],st[100];
  printf("\nEnter a string");
  scanf("%s",str);
  lenght=strlen(str);
  for(i=0,j=(lenght-1);str[i]!='\0',j>=0;i++,j--)
   {
      st[j]=str[i];
   }
  st[i]='\0';
  printf("\nThe reversed string is %s\n",st);
 }
```